# Is there any plugin who allows members of my website to add images of their own?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I own a T-shirt website and I want users to add there own designs so I can print them on T-shirts.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using some contact form which your users use to contact you on your WordPress website.

Most popular and reliable free plugin for contact forms is CF7 or Contact Form 7: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

If you use above plugin or similar plugin for creation of your contact form in WordPress, in CF7 there is a field type you can add called: **FILE** http://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/ , which you can add to your form and then users can easily send you image form using that form.

See sample screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vPJC.jpg , of the form created using free plugin CF7 which have file field added.